# Is there a web view of my synchronized Google Chrome bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Google Chrome synchronizes my bookmarks between computers. When I am away from a computer that has Chrome on it is there a way to view these bookmarks on the web?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently, no, there is no way to view your Chrome bookmarks on the web.  You will need to use Chrome or some other 3rd party extension to get access to your bookmarks.  There is no URL or drive folder for Chrome bookmarks that can be viewed directly in a browser.

Prior to the release of Google Bookmarks there was the ability to view your [Google Chrome Bookmarks via Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1185251):

> In the previous version of the
>   Documents List, if you were using the
>   syncing feature in Chrome, your
>   bookmarks were saved in a folder in
>   the Documents List. With the newer
>   version of the Documents List, we're
>   no longer offering this feature;
>   however, your settings in Chrome
>   continue to sync across computers.

There is an option for a web interface for [Google Bookmarks](http://www.google.com/bookmarks) - however it is old and not related to Chrome bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for a web interface for the google bookmarks [link](http://www.google.com/bookmarks). I don't know when it was set up, but it works.

Comment: This is separate from the bookmarks that Chrome syncs. Interestingly, it's presently showing me the list of places I've stared in Google Maps on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I realize this is 3 years old but it's the top option on Google and the problem hasn't gone away...

What I do is periodically download the Chrome bookmarks HTML file (go to `chrome://bookmarks/`, then under `Organize` -> export the HTML file). The easiest way would be to simply host with Dropbox or similar (you could even do Google Drive) and while it isn't very pretty, it is still then available. It doesn't sync, though, but a lot of times, if you do this every once in a while, that's enough for when you need a website but don't remember the URL. What I would personally love is a combination between [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) and http://www.clippingsconverter.com/ (which is for Kindle clippings but the same concept). It would be separately hosted with a better interface then the default HTML file.

Comment: Can you do this on mobile Chrome?

Comment: To answer my own question, it doesn't even load the URL!

Answer (score -1):

Other options using third party tools like http://www.xmarks.com/ include

1. http://www.linkcloud.org/
2. http://www.bookmarksany.com/
3. http://www.boodori.com/
4. https://icrumz.com/
5. http://markitbot.com/